# how to determine whether a variable is array in Painless, Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I want to remove an element in array, if the field is not array, do nothing.

```
if (ctx._source?.field != null) {
  ctx._source.field.remove(ctx._source.field.indexOf('value'))
}
```

In order to do so, it has to determine whether the field is an array, or exception is expected.
How?

In addition, is there detailed instruction of Painless? There is only get-started in elasticsearch website.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171394/4604579 (hint: use `instanceof`)

Comment: @Val you must be an expert of Painless

Comment: Did it work out?

Comment: @Val absolutely

Comment: Maybe put that as an answer?